# Will a private subdomain negatively affect my SEO on the main domain site?

Tags: seo, subdomain

I have launched a subdomain website for admin purposes. Simply for staff and clients to login and view private pages. I've ticked to discourage search engines to index it as I don't want it to be found.

However, I am concerned that discouraging search engines on the subdomain may impact the way they crawl the main public domain. Therefore, should I set it up on a completely different domain or is it fine to leave things as they are?

Comment: What makes you think that a subdomain being private will affect the primary domain?

Comment: I just want to make sure that it won't impact it negatively? Basically just worried in case it does.

Comment: When you say "ticked to discourage search engines" does that mean that it is powered by WordPress?  The "Discourage Search Engine" option in WordPress creates a robots.txt file that disallows all crawling.  Or are you using some other platform or using some other mechanism like password protecting the whole thing?

Comment: Yes its a basic wordpress website on the subdomain and I have ticked to discourage search engines. The pages on it are all password protected - just with the basic password option for viewing wordpress pages.

Answer (score 1):

Google treats subdomains as *separate domains*. Your admin subdomain will not affect the organic visibility of your main site.

Unless the content is sensitive/confidential, don't worry!

If it is confidential, I would recommend something like Cloudflare - when we “discourage” (disallow in robots.txt, no follow) Google *respects this*.

Other bots, especially malicious ones, have no obligation to honor this request. They will not respect it.